# I launched a new Facebook App, how can I select my existing fan-page as the app's community page?

Tags: facebook-apps, facebook-page

We have been developing our game for months.

For all those months, we have been creating a community fan-page and we spent several hundred of euros in advertising our fan-page.

Now we are going to launch the game finally, but when I try to connect my existing fan-page as the app’s community page, I only get the option to create a new one.

How can I connect with my new app my fan-page? Or can I to migrate the likes to the new fan-page?

I reject to assume we have wasted so much money building a useless fan-page!!!

Comment: You could try to merge the pages: https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=249601088403018